# UIButton inside UIBarButtonItem discards the animating effect

Tags: objective-c, animation, ios7, uibarbuttonitem

If I embed a `UIButton` inside a `UIBarButtonItem` to put it on a toolbar it discards the animating effect when I tap it.

iOS 7, by default, have a nice animating effect when you tap on a `UIBarButtonItem`. It slighty fades to a lighter color.

How can I keep this gladly effect even on custom `UIBarButtonItem` with background images?

Answer (score -1):

I had experienced the same problem when I created multiple rightbarbuttonitems with custom UIView & image. I solved my problem by using `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` property.

```
 yourCustomButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

Comment: I just edited your answer to fix formatting, didn't downvote it.

Comment: ups sorry, misunderstanding :)